# identify if matrices have NAs in the same position (logical)

Tags: r, function, matrix

i want to identify whether two matrices have NA's in the same spot.

Setup:
We have three matrices. I want to run a function that tells me mat1 and mat2 have NA's in identical spots, and that tells me that mat1(and mat3) vs mat2 have NA's in different spots

```
mat1 <- matrix(nrow=2, ncol =2, data =c(NA,0,0,NA))
mat2 <- matrix(nrow=2, ncol =2, data=c(NA,0,0,NA))
mat3 <- matrix(nrow=2, ncol=2, data = c(NA,0,0,0))
```

Comment: Please show what was attempted in order to arrive at the solution.

Comment: If the matrices are the same dimensions, you can just use `identical(is.na(m1), is.na(m2))`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Compare the NA status of all elements:

```
> all(is.na(mat1) == is.na(mat2))
[1] TRUE
> all(is.na(mat1) == is.na(mat3))
[1] FALSE
```

In a function I'd do this:

```
> nanana = function(m1, m2){!any(is.na(m1) != is.na(m2))}
```

I've inverted the logic so that `any` can stop checking if it finds any difference. If you use `all` it has to go over every element. I'm not sure if this kind of short-circuiting is in R but it might save you a millisecond or two.

```
> nanana(mat1, mat2)
[1] TRUE
> nanana(mat1, mat3)
[1] FALSE
```

Answer (score 2):

We can write a function which compares the position of `NA` elements in two matrix

```
identical_NA_matrix <- function(m1, m2) {
   identical(which(is.na(m1), arr.ind = TRUE), which(is.na(m2), arr.ind = TRUE))
}

identical_NA_matrix(mat1,mat3)
#[1] FALSE
identical_NA_matrix(mat1,mat2)
#[1] TRUE
```